# How can multiple substrings of a String be replaced with multiple values in java?

Tags: java, string, replace, find, substring

I have a long String which is dynamic. Wherever % XXX % is found, I have to get the XXX value and replace it with some other value. There will be multiple % XXX %.
How can I get the value within the % %?

For Eg.

```
"POLICY_NO = %POLNO%  and b.ACTION_TIME = (select max(ACTION_TIME) from POLICY_DETAILS where POLICY_NO = %POLICYID%)"
```

How can I read each value between 2 `%`? And I have to take POLNO and compare it with some session variables(Eg,POLNO=1234567,POLICYID=3) and if it is matched then i have to replace the session variable value. Then the query sholud become as

"POLICY_NO = 1234567 and b.ACTION_TIME = (select max(ACTION_TIME) from POLICY_DETAILS where POLICY_NO = 3)"

Comment: So each different "property" in the string should be replaced with a different value? Are all the possible "properties" known in advance (i.e. there are 6 possible values)?

Comment: Properties are possible values like POLNO, POLID.. I have to get the values from 2 % first. Next Compare with Map keys..If found then have to replace with Map Value of the specific Key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering only the substitution in strings:

- If you don't know which variables you should replace or its values, you can do is:

  ```
  // Map simulate your session variables.
  Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
  variables.put("POLNO", "V1");
  variables.put("POLICYID", "V2");

  String input =
  /**/"POLICY_NO = %POLNO% and A.POLICY_DETAILS_ID = " +
  /**/"b.POLICY_DETAILS_ID and b.ACTION_TIME = " +
  /**/"(select max(ACTION_TIME) from POLICY_DETAILS " +
  /**/"where POLICY_NO = %POLICYID%)";

  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input);

  int offset = 0;

  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(%)([^%]*)(%)").matcher(input);
  while (matcher.find()) {
      // Get only second group (variable name), ignoring % symbols
      String variable = matcher.group(2);
      String value = variables.get(variable);

      // Calculate the offset.
      // The previous replaces can change the string length
      int start = matcher.start() + offset;
      int end = matcher.end() + offset;

      // Replace %XXX% by its value
      output.replace(start, end, value);

      offset -= variable.length() + 2 - value.length();
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, you can chain multiply calls:

  ```
  String.replace("%XXX%", "VALUE")
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Look at `String.format()` class method method, but if it is for SQL you should consider using `PreparedStatement` those are standard java classes.

Here is an example of String.format

```
String formatted = String.format("%d is a number and %s is another string", 20, "Test");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: That is okay.. But the possible variables  like POLNO, POLID.. I have to get the variable from 2 % first. Next Compare with Map keys..If found then have to replace with Map Value of the specific Key...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to get all strings between two percent characters (%). For this, try the following expression: `%([^%]*)%`

You'd still have to evaluate the strings you found.

Alternatively, if you know what could occur here (or what should be supported) just use `someString.replace("%POLNO%", "somevalue")`.

Howver, if this is for SQL, you might want to look into prepared statements (with [some extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970/named-parameters-in-jdbc)) or some OR mapper instead. What you basically have in that case is named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you should use `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL injection.

But if you decide to do replacement in String, `appendReplacement` works fine:

```
final String in = "POLICY_NO = %POLNO% and A.POLICY_DETAILS_ID = b.POLICY_DETAILS_ID and b.ACTION_TIME = (select max(ACTION_TIME) from POLICY_DETAILS where POLICY_NO = %POLICYID%)";

// initialize map
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put( "POLNO", "1234567" );
map.put( "POLICYID", "3" );

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "%.*?%" );
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( in );
final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ( matcher.find() ) {
    final String found = matcher.group();
    final String withoutPercents = found.substring( 1, found.length() - 1 );
    matcher.appendReplacement( sb, map.get( withoutPercents ) );
    // instead of map.get(), there could be session.getAttribute( withoutPercents  )
}
matcher.appendTail( sb );
System.out.println( sb.toString() );
```

**UPD**: according to comment below

Comment: Hi Betlista, There the map contains only the session variables only..But not with %... so please enhance it to work with only POLNO, POLNOID...