# Exception in query

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm getting an error while executing following select query:

```
ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from login where username="+username+"and password ="+password);
```

And the exception is

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

Please let me know if the query is wrong syntactically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

single quotations are missing before the value and password ,I think it should be :

```
ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from login where username='"+username+"' and password ='"+password+"'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use at least parameters (named parameters are even better). Concatenating values into SQL string is error prone and unsafe. E.g.:

```
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "select * from login where username=? and password=?";
try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        stmt.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
           //...
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        //TODO handle e
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no space between your username and the `and` keyword.  This will parse to

> select * from login where username=usernameand password =password

You're also missing single quotes around the values you're inserting into the statement.  Try:

> ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from login where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'");

I'd also recommend reading about [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in the Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

values for username and password should be in quotes

```
ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from login where username='" + username + "' and password ='" + password + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you are missing few white spaces and quote marks):

```
ResultSet rs = 
  St.executeQuery(
    "select * from login where username=\""+username+"\" and password =\""+password + "\"");
```

Also read about [Named parameters in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970) and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from login where username='"+username+"' and password ='"+password+"'");
```

Best way to execute query take it out and try it on your own...
for ex.

```
String query = "select * from login where username='"+username+"' and password = '"+password+"'";

//Print your query and execute it in your sql client you ll get to know if it works!
System.out.println(query);

ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery(query);
```