# Java MySQL query named parameters?

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way to have named parameters in Java MySQL query?

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = :val1 AND col2 = :val2
```

instead of this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?
```

UPDATE: Im' using `java.sql.*`, however would be interested in alternatives capable of this.

Comment: Using plain JDBC, no. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2309970/1065197

Comment: Are there alternatives to JDBC that can do this then?

Comment: I've updated my comment. Just search for *java jdbc namedparameter* on the net and you will have lot of answers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This looks promising, I'll take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Hibernate is good choice for you. It provided the query style as your description, and it's so powerful and convenient to do persistence work that you'll feel cool.
e.g

```
Query query = sesion.createQuery("from Student s where s.age = :age");
query.setProperties(student);
```

see the doc:[http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/) library lets you do this and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are alternatives. By example, with `javax.persistence.*` you can achieve that quite easily.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

An entity manager will allow you to create dynamic (parametrized) queries with the methods `EntityManager.createQuery`, and `EntityManager.createNamedQuery`.