# Sql query with bind variables execution in Jdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a sql query like this.

```
 select "DEPT"."DEPTNO" as "DEPTNO1",
"DEPT"."DNAME" as "DNAME1",
"DEPT"."LOC" as "LOC1",
"EMP"."COMM" as "COMM1",
"EMP"."EMPNO" as "EMPNO1",
"EMP"."ENAME" as "ENAME1",
"EMP"."HIREDATE" as "HIREDATE1",
"EMP"."JOB" as "JOB1",
"EMP"."MGR" as "MGR1",
"EMP"."SAL" as "SAL1"
from "EMP" , "DEPT" where "DEPT"."DEPTNO" in (:DeptNo)
```

//This is the Jdbc code

```
Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
Statement statment = dbConnection.createStatement();
result = statment.execute(query);//query is above sql query
```

When i run above query in Oracle sql developer works perfectly.But when i run it with above jdbc code it is throwing Not all variables bound exception.
How to run above query in JDBC

Comment: post up the exact error that u get plz. post up the stack trace. post up your all code u have plz.

Comment: You have a named parameter in your query (:DeptNo), but you are not assigning it a value.

Comment: ORA-01008: not all variables bound. This error i'm getting when i run above sql query in JDBC

Comment: I want to execute the query as it is with JDBC

Comment: Above query running in Oracle Sql developer perfectly ,not in Jdbc.

Comment: but at run time i'll get more number of queries and even i dont know about how many bind variables will be there.

Comment: @obulesub bind variables means what?

Comment: above query is having :DeptNo as bind variable, as a parameter

Comment: @obulesub so do you mean to say that DeptNo is a variable?

Comment: `:DeptNo` is not a legal variable for a JDBC prepared statement. Please read the JavaDocs (or the JDBC tutorial)

Comment: it is the query i'm getting at runtime and need to validate that query, here i dont know how many bind variables will come in that query.I'm taking that query and need to check it is running successfully or with errors.

Comment: @obulesub do you have a gmail?I need more information to answer your question

Comment: obulesu.dynasoft@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the query dynamically from the report.

From this query we need to split querystring to get number of bind variables and placing those bind variables in a HashMap.HashMap is like

```
            {DeptName =1, Job =1, DeptNo =1}
```

From this hashmap,need to replace the query bind variable with `?`.For this we need to do like

```
   bindkey = entry1.getKey().toString();
    String bindkeyreplace =":".concat(bindkey).trim();
    String bindkeyreplacestring = "?";
    query = query.replace(bindkeyreplace, bindkeyreplacestring);
```

Then we will get dynamic query coming from the report with `?` instead of `:bindvariable`

```
        PreparedStatement prestmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < bindParamMap.size(); i++) {
             prestmt.setInt(i + 1, 0);//Setting default value to check the query is running successfully or not
        }
        result = prestmt.execute();
```

If in case, we don't know how many bind variables we get then this approach is running successfully for me.

Answer (score 6):

replace `:deptno` in your query with a ?.

and instead of instantiating statement use the following:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setInt(1,deptno); //1 is for the first question mark
```

where `deptno` holds the value for which you want to execute the query.

Through PrepredStatement interface we can use parametrized query which is compiled only once and has performance advantage in comparison to the Statement interface.

Comment: runtime even i dont know how many bind variables that a query having.

Comment: The query that you have mentioned above has only one bind variable and that is :deptno
Are you not sure of the query?

Comment: mentioned one sample query, in runtime i'll get more no. of queries which may contain several bind variable

Comment: May I know What is the source of the query? or how the query is being generated and when does it change?

Comment: Query is generated according to the report and we dont know how many bind variables it is having. According to the reports, query will change.

Comment: Please refer the following document (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/) 

 that talks about the generation of dynamic query in a Jasper Report:

Refer to the paragraph that begins with the following:
$X{} 

There are also cases when just using $P{} in the report query is not enough, because parts of the query need to be dynamically built, depending on one or more report parameter values, in order to construct a valid query.....

If the reporting Tool is Something else Please Let me know!

Answer (score 4):

You created a Query with bind variable and you never set it.

Use `OraclePreparedStatement` and its method `setStringAtName()`

```
statement.setStringAtName("DeptNo","<<your Value>>");
```

If not `OraclePreparedStatement`, you can just put it as `?1` in your Query string
and use,

```
statement.setString(1,"<<your Value>>");
```

If in case, you don't know how many bind variables you get, you have capture the bind variables in a map and prepare a list and set it accordingly!

Else your requirement is unachievable!

Comment: OraclePreparedStatement prestmt =
                (OraclePreparedStatement)dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
            prestmt.setStringAtName("DeptNo","DeptNo");
            result = prestmt.execute(query);//throwing Attempt to set a parameter name that does not occur in the SQL: DeptNo

Comment: Please print your Query string and confirm the name of the bind variable.. It is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax,`EMP.DNAME as DNAME1`. I mean your dot and as must be inside the double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

The variable DeptNo must be bound to a value before you execute the statement like below.

```
DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
Statement statment = dbConnection.createStatement();
//Bind deptno to a value
statment.setParameter("DeptNo",5);
result = statment.execute(query);
```

You must set values for all the variables in your prepared statement othwerise you cannot execute the statement. If you receive the query to execute itself as an input then you should also get the parameters and its values also as input. Something like below

```
public <returnType> executeQuery(String queryStr, Map<String,Object> params) {
     //Code to create connecitno and statment from queryStr.
     //Bind deptno to a value
     for(int i=0;i<params.size(),i++) {
       //Get entry set from map  
       statment.setParameter(entryset.getKey(),entryset.getValue());
     }

     result = statment.execute(query);
     //return or work on the result      
}
```

Comment: but at run time i'll get more number of queries and even i dont know about how many bind variables will be there.

Comment: is this method present setParameter()?

Comment: setParameter is not directly present in PreparedStatement. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970/named-parameters-in-jdbc and http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html to mimic that facility.

Comment: @thiyaga how can you write statment.setParameter()

Comment: @JqueryLearner, It is only a wapper method which was written. actual method  will be either setInt ot setString or SetObject etc.. We can write a wrapper method named setParameter that checks the class type of the parameter and utilizes the corresponding method on the prepared statement.

Comment: @thiyaga Its not present in statement but Its present in preparedStatement