# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException JAVA + PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm doing a delete button to delete data from db.

It is my Java code

```
  private void btnUsunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
      try
      {
    int P = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Jesteś pewny usunięcia ?","Potwierdzenie",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
 if (P==0)
 {
    String query = "{CALL SZPITAL_DB.usun_uzytkownik(?)}" ;
        CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall(query); 
        cst.setString(1,txtLogin.getText());
        cst.execute();
        cst.close();     
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Usunięto !","Potwierdzenie",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            Reset();
 }
  }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex); 
            }

}
```

PL/SQL Code

```
create or replace procedure usun_uzytkownik
(
       ID IN LOGOWANIE.LOGIN%TYPE   
)
  IS
begin 
delete LOGOWANIE WHERE LOGIN = ID;

commit;
end usun_uzytkownik;
```

And the problem is that i'm using this code in another class and works good.

When i run it here i got an error:

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Uzytkownicy.btnUsunActionPerformed(Uzytkownicy.java:309)
        at Uzytkownicy.access$200(Uzytkownicy.java:13)
        at Uzytkownicy$3.actionPerformed(Uzytkownicy.java:90)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Here is a full class code:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Uzytkownicy extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection con=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;


    public Uzytkownicy() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    private void Reset()
{
    txtImie.setText("");
    txtLogin.setText("");
    txtHaslo.setText("");
    txtEmail.setText("");
    cmbStatus.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    Zapisz.setEnabled(true);
    btnUsun.setEnabled(false);
    Nadpisz.setEnabled(false);
    txtLogin.requestDefaultFocus();

}

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Nowy = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Zapisz = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnUsun = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Nadpisz = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtImie = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtLogin = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtHaslo = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtEmail = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmbStatus = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        Użytkownicy = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Użytkownicy");
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        Nowy.setText("Nowy");
        Nowy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NowyActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Zapisz.setText("Zapisz");
        Zapisz.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ZapiszActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnUsun.setText("Usuń");
        btnUsun.setEnabled(false);
        btnUsun.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnUsunActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Nadpisz.setText("Nadpisz");
        Nadpisz.setEnabled(false);
        Nadpisz.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NadpiszActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Nowy, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Zapisz, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnUsun, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Nadpisz, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Nowy, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(Zapisz, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnUsun, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(Nadpisz, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Użytkownicy"));

        jLabel1.setText("Nazwa");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

        jLabel2.setText("Login");

        jLabel3.setText("Hasło");

        jLabel4.setText("Email");

        jLabel5.setText("Status");

        cmbStatus.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "admin", "pacjent", "lekarz" }));
        cmbStatus.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(txtLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtEmail)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(cmbStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(txtHaslo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 212, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(txtImie, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)))
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(txtImie, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(txtHaslo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(txtEmail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(cmbStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        Użytkownicy.setText("Użytkownicy");
        Użytkownicy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                UżytkownicyActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Zamknij");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Zdjecia/icon-users.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                .addComponent(Użytkownicy, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Użytkownicy, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void NowyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Reset();
    }                                    

    private void ZapiszActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         try{
      con=Polaczenie.ConnectDB();
       if (txtImie.getText().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Podaj imię","Błąd !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;
            }
        if (txtLogin.getText().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Podaj login","Błąd !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;
            }
        String Password= String.valueOf(txtHaslo.getPassword());
         if (Password.equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Podaj hasło","Błąd !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;
            }
          if (cmbStatus.getSelectedItem().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Wybierz status","Błąd !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;
            }

       Statement stmt;
       stmt= con.createStatement();
       String sql1="Select LOGIN from SZPITAL_DB.LOGOWANIE where LOGIN= '" + txtLogin.getText() + "'";
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
      if(rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Login zajęty ","Błąd !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtLogin.setText("");
        txtLogin.requestDefaultFocus();
       return;
   }       
       String query = "{CALL SZPITAL_DB.zapisz_uzytkownik(?,?,?,?,?)}" ;
            CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall(query); 
            cst.setString(1,txtLogin.getText());
            cst.setString(2,txtHaslo.getText());
            cst.setString(3,txtImie.getText());
            cst.setString(4,(String)cmbStatus.getSelectedItem());
            cst.setString(5,txtEmail.getText());
            cst.execute();
            cst.close();     

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Zapisano","Potwierdzenie !",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
      Zapisz.setEnabled(false);
        }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex); 
                }
    }                                      

    private void btnUsunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
          try
          {
        int P = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Jesteś pewny usunięcia ?","Potwierdzenie",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
     if (P==0)
     {
        String query = "{CALL SZPITAL_DB.usun_uzytkownik(?)}" ;
            CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall(query); 
            cst.setString(1,txtLogin.getText());
            cst.execute();
            cst.close();     
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Usunięto !","Potwierdzenie",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Reset();
     }
      }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex); 
                }

    }                                       

    private void NadpiszActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try{
      con=Polaczenie.ConnectDB();
     String Password1= String.valueOf(txtHaslo.getPassword());
       String sql= "update Registration set password='" + Password1 + "',nameofuser='" + txtImie.getText() + "',Email='" + txtEmail.getText() + "' where Username='" + txtLogin.getText() + "'";

      pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.execute();
       String sql2= "update Users set user_password='" + Password1 + "' where username='" + txtLogin.getText() + "'";

      pst=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
      pst.execute();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successfully updated","User info",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
      Nadpisz.setEnabled(false);
        }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex); 
                }
    }                                       

    private void UżytkownicyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
      this.hide();
      UzytkonikTabela frm = new UzytkonikTabela();
      frm.setVisible(true); 
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     this.hide();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uzytkownicy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uzytkownicy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uzytkownicy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uzytkownicy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Uzytkownicy().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JButton Nadpisz;
    private javax.swing.JButton Nowy;
    private javax.swing.JButton Użytkownicy;
    public javax.swing.JButton Zapisz;
    public javax.swing.JButton btnUsun;
    public javax.swing.JComboBox cmbStatus;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    public javax.swing.JTextField txtEmail;
    public javax.swing.JPasswordField txtHaslo;
    public javax.swing.JTextField txtImie;
    public javax.swing.JTextField txtLogin;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not working this

Comment: A reason of NPE is that probably `con` field is not initalized yet (is NULL) when the procedure is callled.

Comment: Based on the other two ActionPerformed methods I think you are missing this `con=Polaczenie.ConnectDB();` beforehand. Note, sql statements like `String sql= "update Registration set password='" + Password1 + "',nameofuser='" + txtImie.getText() + "',Email='" + txtEmail.getText() + "' where Username='" + txtLogin.getText() + "'";` are a very, very, very, very bad thing! They open all sorts of security vulnerabilities and other things. You should always use bind variables instead! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604736/sql-query-with-bind-variables-execution-in-jdbc