# What is the meaning of "?1"

Tags: java, sql

What is the meaning of "?1" actually. Can someone explain to me.Thanks in advance.

**Example code:**

```
(SQL.append(" SELECT ComModules.id, ComModules.description ")
                        .append(" FROM ComAccessModules as ComAccessModules, ComModules as ComModules ")
                        .append(" WHERE ")
                        .append(" ComAccessModules.comAccessModulesPK.modId=ComModules.id ")
                        .append(" AND ")
                        .append(" ComAccessModules.comAccessModulesPK.accessId=?1 ")))
```

Comment: ?1 is just the parameter , as is rendered in HQL

Comment: Before executing this statement you should add a value to replace the ?1 in the query.

See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309984/5118375) about using parameterized queries.

Furthermore read up on sql injection and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a placeholder that gets filled with whatever you give it as parameter at execution of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is an unnamed parameter which can be filled in by a program running the query. :)