# Can I use named parameters in an INSERT PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I would like a suggestion, then usually I load data on the database in this way:

```
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME, LAST NAME) VALUES (?,?)");
             prep.setString (1, name);
             prep.setString (2, last name);
             prep.executeUpdate ();
```

I would like a way to avoid indicate a data reference index, that is, I would like to send data to the PreparedStatement untidily
no index, I would like to send the data and then it will be the API to set the correct fields, it could use something like this (note that I reversed the surname with the name, sending the last name first, and the API should add it to the second field )

```
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME, LAST NAME) VALUES (?,?)");
             prep.setString (surname, name);
             prep.setString (NAME, name);
             prep.executeUpdate ();
```

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC standard does not support named parameter markers in `PreparedStatement`, however, some vendor implementations of the JDBC driver do support them -- here's an example of the [DB2 JDBC extension](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_t0054762.html). Check documentation for your particular database vendor's driver implementation.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc does not natively support named parameters in prepared statements. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309984/4385713) that might answer your question.

Depending on the database you use (Oracle, MySQL, etc.) you may need slightly different tools.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JAVA `PreparedStatement` documentation from [ORACLE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). There is no such methods.

The methods that are available looks generally like this:

`set...(int parameterIndex, SomeObject variableName)`