# Parameter @x was not defined for stored procedure... with MS_SQL JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using SQL Server JDBC in a method:

```
//Connection connection, String sp_name, Map<String, Object>params input to the method
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
HashMap<String, Integer> paramInfo = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if (dbMetaData != null)
{
        ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns (null, null, sp_name.toUpperCase(), "%");
        while (rs.next())
            paramInfo.put(rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(6));
        rs.close();
}
String call = "{ call " + sp_name + " ( ";
for (int i = 0; i < paramInfo.size(); i ++)
    call += "?,";
if (paramInfo.size() > 0)
    call = call.substring(0, call.length() - 1);
call += " ) }";
CallableStatement st = connection.prepareCall (call);
for (String paramName: paramInfo.keySet()){
    int paramType = paramInfo.get(paramName);
    System.out.println("paramName="+paramName);
    System.out.println("paramTYpe="+paramType);
    Object paramVal = params.get(paramName);
    st.setInt(paramName, Integer.parseInt(((String)paramVal))); //All stored proc parameters are of type int
}
```

Let say the stored procedure name is `ABC` and parameter is `@a`. 
Now `DatabaseMetaData` returns column name `@a` but setting `st.setInt("@a",0)` returns following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter @a was not defined for stored procedure ABC.

Instead, I tried this: `st.setInt("a",0)` and it executed perfectly.

Now the problem is I have to set the parameters dynamically as I have too many stored procedures and too many parameters but jdbc is giving error.

**Edit 1:**

As pointed out in one answer that my question is a duplicate of: [Named parameters in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970/named-parameters-in-jdbc), I would like to explain that the issue here is not named parameters or positional ones, rather it is about JDBC not handling the SQL server parameters itself properly or my making some error while invoking it.

Comment: not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but why can(t you dynamically strip off the `@` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named parameters in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970/named-parameters-in-jdbc)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I need something that works with both mysql and sql server and some others too without making specific changes as I expect JDBC to take care of it.

Comment: @Bejasc `CallableStatement` is the exception to that rule: it does support named parameters.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, you might want to report it on https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc Either the metadata should report the names without `@`, or the `setXXX` should accept it with `@` (and without for backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2017-10-07: The [merge request to fix this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/495) has been accepted, so this should no longer be a problem with versions [6.3.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v6.3.4) and later.

---

Yes, it is an unfortunate inconsistency that for mssql-jdbc the parameter names returned by `DatabaseMetaData#getProcedureColumns` do not match the names accepted by `CallableStatement#setInt` *et. al.*. If you consider it to be a bug then you should create an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues) and perhaps it will be fixed in a future release.

In the meantime, however, you'll just have to work around it. So, instead of code like this ...

```java
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getProcedureColumns(null, "dbo", "MenuPlanner", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getShort("COLUMN_TYPE") == DatabaseMetaData.procedureColumnIn) {
        String inParamName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        System.out.println(inParamName);
    }
}
```

... which produces ...

```
@person
@food
```

... you'll need to use code like this ...

```java
boolean isMssqlJdbc = connection.getClass().getName().equals(
        "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection");
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getProcedureColumns(null, "dbo", "MenuPlanner", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getShort("COLUMN_TYPE") == DatabaseMetaData.procedureColumnIn) {
        String inParamName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        if (isMssqlJdbc && inParamName.startsWith("@")) {
            inParamName = inParamName.substring(1, inParamName.length());
        }
        System.out.println(inParamName);
    }
}
```

... which produces ...

```
person
food
```

Comment: GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/496).

Comment: When can I expect this to be incorporated in the sql driver?

Comment: @HBK - I'm not a Microsoft employee so I can't say. You could try asking over on GitHub.

Comment: @HBK - Version [6.3.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v6.3.4) was released on October 19.