# String Utils join in not working as expected

Tags: java, list, apache-stringutils, string-utils

I have a list of strings which is returned from a query in List A.

I am trying to use String Utils.join to combine the values in the list to a string separated by comma and in quotes. But it is not working as expected.

Values in abcList - [abc, cde, fgh]

```
abcList.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(abcSql, String.class));
String abc= StringUtils.join(abcList, "','");
abc = "'" +abc+ "'";
```

Expected output - 'abc', 'cde', 'fgh'
Actual output - 'abc, cde, fgh'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as I want to pass the values form the string abc into query with "IN" condition.

Comment: Which `StringUtils` are you using?

Comment: Works as expected on my computer.. Which version of StringUtils are you using?

Comment: Working as expected using `lang3` version 3.7

Comment: Using this import import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils with jar version 3.1

Comment: Why don't you just use the query `abcSql` itself directly as a subquery in the `IN` clause instead of getting the actual strings?

Comment: I cannot use the abcSql directly in the in clause because the column that it will return contains comma separated strings instead of multiple rows. So thats why I was not able to use StringUtil.join as expected. Since it is a single string. Found my mistake. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you can also use `stream.Collectors.joining`

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi");
String joined = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
System.out.println(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use the native method for joining strings.

```
List<String> list = <get a list of strings somehow>;
String joinedString = String.join("','", list);
```

[See the String.join javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Just as a hint for JDBC queries...you should use named parameters for inserting the values in your query instead of manually constructing the query string.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309970/named-parameters-in-jdbc) SO post for an example.

Comment: Too bad, than @Erithrean's answer won't work either. Nevertheless, you should use named parameters for the query anyways (see my edit). If you do this, you won't have to add the quotes manually.

Comment: But these values, which are then used in an IN clause, come from another query.The OP should use that query directly as a subquery, instead of executing it, getting the result and injecting that into another query.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes, I absolutely agree that it should be done that way. But I think it's still worth clarifying the misconception of how set parameters in a query, as it is security relevant in other cases.